# Java + Reactor: Http call for each record

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I have a `Stream<A>` that I want to iterate over and fetch additional information about each record from another service. In the end it should become a `Stream<B>`.

Since I am using `Jetty` I can't use `.block()`.

How do I do that using Reactor Project?

Comment: You'd need a reactive HTTP client like `WebClient`, which is part of `Spring WebFlux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flatMap:

```java
Flux<A> fluxA = //...;
Flux<B> fluxB = sampleFlux.flatMap(elem -> fetchDataFromRemoteService(elem));
```

where fetchDataFromRemoteService(A a) return Publisher.

Or you can use Flux#concatMap:

```java
Flux<A> fluxA = //...;
Flux<B> fluxB = sampleFlux.concatMap(elem -> fetchDataFromRemoteService(elem));
```

The difference between flatMap and concatMap will be that in the second case, all actions will follow each other.

Or:

```java
Stream<B> streamB =  Flux.fromStream(streamA)
                         .flatMap(this::fetchDataFromRemoteService)
                         .toStream();
```