# Collecting information from Flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I encounter this situation very often when working with reactive webflux. Basically I am trying to call a service that returns a flux. In this case `Flux<Marks>`

```
Class Marks{
int Sid;
int Mark;
}
```

I have a `List<Student>` in which I need to update marks field using the response from above service

```
Class Student{
int Sid;
int Mark;
String School;
}
```

how to do this.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> mapIdMarks = new HashMap<>();
Flux<Marks> fluxMarks = externalService.getAllMarks();

// HOW TO DO BELOW OPERATION IN REACTIVE FLUX SINCE FOREACH IS NOT AVAILABE ON FLUX
fluxMarks.foreach(marks -> mapIdMarks.put(marks.getSid().marks.getMark()));

// then from here on mapIdMarks can be used to fill up missing marks information in List<Student>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java + Reactor: Http call for each record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122729/java-reactor-http-call-for-each-record)

Comment: No. I can only get back all data at once. Fetch for each record from external service one by one will be a huge performance issue

Comment: read the solution, not the question, the answer is right there. the solution is literally in the FIRST SENTENCE of the answer.

Comment: u mean using flatmap?  Can please explain how to use it in my scenario please?

Comment: in the other post you pointed to me the answer uses 2 flux. In my case I have a flux and a list. Can tell me how flatmap can be used here then? And what is that sampleFlux?

Answer (score -1):

This is what i learnt

1. If you are trying to return List from the function that does this operation then this is a bad design as we should never try to combine reactive and non reactive code unless we are at the very end of our processing

   //dont do this
   Map<Integer,Integer> listStudents combineMarks(List listStudents)
   {
   }

Do this instead

```
Mono<Map<Integer,Integer>> listStudents combineMarks(List<Student> listStudents)
{
  Flux<Marks> fluxMarks = externalService.getAllMarks();
     return fluxMarks.collectList()
               .zipWith(Mono.just(listStudents))
               .map(turple -> {
                      List<Marks> listMarks = turple.getT1();
                      List<Student> listStudent = turple.getT2();
                      Map<Integer,Integer> mapIdMarks = new HashMap<>();

                     //now you have all the infomation in listMarks and listStudent to create Map<Integer,Integer> mapIdMarks = new HashMap<> here
});

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).